# Is it possible to build a .vrt file from multiple files with Rasterio?

Tags: python, rasterio, vrt, gdalbuildvrt

I would like to build a vrt file from multiple dataset. I know the [`gdalbuildvrt`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalbuildvrt.html) but i don't find how I'm supposed to do the same using rasterio [vrt object](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.vrt.html).

Does anyone have a simple example ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very naive way using `rasterio.shutil.copy` to generate VRT XML for each source raster, combine them and output a stacked VRT (equivalent to `gdalbuildvrt -separate`).

By naive, I mean it does not check any of the properties and assumes rasters are all the same shape, extent, pixel size, data type, projection etc.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.shutil import copy as riocopy
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile


def stack_vrts(srcs, band=1):
    vrt_bands = []
    for srcnum, src in enumerate(srcs, start=1):
        with rio.open(src) as ras, MemoryFile() as mem:
            riocopy(ras, mem.name, driver='VRT')
            vrt_xml = mem.read().decode('utf-8')
            vrt_dataset = ET.fromstring(vrt_xml)
            for bandnum, vrt_band in enumerate(vrt_dataset.iter('VRTRasterBand'), start=1):
                if bandnum == band:
                    vrt_band.set('band', str(srcnum))
                    vrt_bands.append(vrt_band)
                    vrt_dataset.remove(vrt_band)
    for vrt_band in vrt_bands:
        vrt_dataset.append(vrt_band)

    return ET.tostring(vrt_dataset).decode('UTF-8')


srcs = ['test1.tif', 'test2.tif', 'test3.tif']

with rio.open(stack_vrts(srcs)) as src:
    print(src.profile)
```

Comment: As I'm building the images myself, I'm in full control over them (properties wise) so I think solution is exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, rasterio does not let you build VRTs, but you can do this easily with GDAL's Python bindings:

```py
import rasterio
from osgeo import gdal

filepaths = ['a.tif', 'b.tif']  # list of paths to raster files
vrt_path = 'temp.vrt'  # path to vrt to build
gdal.BuildVRT(vrt_path, filepaths)
with rasterio.open(vrt_path) as raster:
    pass  # do stuff
```

Comment: I am doing this as well but it's worth knowing that importing rasterio and gdal together can lead to issues:
https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/switch.html#mutual-incompatibilities

Comment: I know that's why I asked the question in the first place

Answer (score 0):

It's a huge issue for me as I can't afford to use conda on my environment, I coded a monkey-patch lib for this very purpose: https://pypi.org/project/rio-vrt/.

It's a vrt builder based on rasterio, which means fully compatible with a pure python installation.

```
from rio_vrt import build_vrt

raster_files = ["example.tif", "example2.tif", "...", "examplen.tif"]
vrt_file = build_vrt("example.vrt", raster_files)
```