# Extract values from multiple rasters to CSV using Python

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio

I want to use an old sofware to analyse my data with a new angle. This software is not compatible with the .tif format so I need to transform all my data into a `.csv`.

The expected `.csv` structure is the following:

| ADM0_CODE | pixel_area | lat | lon | layer1_name | layer2_name | ... | layerN_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I've prepared the data so that all this information (including the 4 first specific columns) are on a list of .tif files with exact same number of pixels, crs etc.

I've tried many things involving `for` loops that are never going to finish and that are eating up all my computer memory.

Is there a canonic way to do it with `gdal` and/or `rasterio` ?

The maps are covering half he world with 1km grid cells so each individual file is about 1.9 Gb and there are 29.

Comment: I can help you to extrac values from a raster and the area, Is it ok for you?

Comment: Do you want to calculate the total area?

Comment: I already have computed the pixel_area of every pixel and stored it in a raster

Comment: I can show you a simple example about how to extrat the raster values with geopandas, Do you agree?

Comment: I mean, yes of course, if you have any solution you can post an answer

Answer (score 1):

Here's a rasterio method that reads your csv and uses the `dataset.sample` method for each of the input rasters.

Note `sample` accepts an iterable of coordinates and returns a generator (hence the `next(sample([[lat, lon]]))` in the code below).

This is pretty slow as it's reading the coordinates and values one by one. It may be quicker to just use gdal_translate to convert to x,y,z format then paste the z values to your input csv. But I've done it this way rather than reading all the coordinates into memory at once because of the size.

```
import csv
from pathlib import Path

import rasterio

dir = Path('path/to/raster_dir')

incsvfile = 'path/to/in.csv'
outcsvfile = 'path/to/out.csv'
rasters = ['test1.tif', 'test2.tif', 'test3.tif']

with open(incsvfile) as incsvfile, open(outcsvfile, 'w', newline='') as outcsvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(incsvfile)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outcsvfile)

    fieldnames = next(csvreader)
    csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)

    datasets = [rasterio.open(dir/raster) for raster in rasters]

    for adm0_code, pixel_area, lat, lon in csvreader:
        values = []
        for src in datasets:
            values.append(next(src.sample([[float(lon), float(lat)]]))[0])

        csvwriter.writerow([adm0_code, pixel_area, lat, lon] + values)
```

And here's a way using the [`stack_vrts` function I showed you previously](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/421687/2856), it's slightly faster.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.shutil import copy as riocopy
from rasterio.io import MemoryFile


def stack_vrts(srcs, band=1):
    vrt_bands = []
    for srcnum, src in enumerate(srcs, start=1):
        with rio.open(src) as ras, MemoryFile() as mem:
            riocopy(ras, mem.name, driver='VRT')
            vrt_xml = mem.read().decode('utf-8')
            vrt_dataset = ET.fromstring(vrt_xml)
            for bandnum, vrt_band in enumerate(vrt_dataset.iter('VRTRasterBand'), start=1):
                if bandnum == band:
                    vrt_band.set('band', str(srcnum))
                    vrt_bands.append(vrt_band)
                    vrt_dataset.remove(vrt_band)
    for vrt_band in vrt_bands:
        vrt_dataset.append(vrt_band)

    return ET.tostring(vrt_dataset).decode('UTF-8')


dir = Path('path/to/raster_dir')

incsvfile = 'path/to/in.csv'
outcsvfile = 'path/to/out.csv'
rasters = ['test1.tif', 'test2.tif', 'test3.tif']

with open(incsvfile) as incsvfile, open(outcsvfile, 'w', newline='') as outcsvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(incsvfile)
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outcsvfile)

    fieldnames = next(csvreader)
    csvwriter.writerow(fieldnames)

    with rio.open(stack_vrts([dir/raster for raster in rasters])) as src:

        for adm0_code, pixel_area, lat, lon in csvreader:
            values = next(src.sample([[float(lon), float(lat)]]))
            csvwriter.writerow([adm0_code, pixel_area, lat, lon] + list(values))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Import modules

import rasterio 
from rasterio import plot
import geopandas as gpd

# Read data (raster and points)

raster = rasterio.open(inputpath_raster)
points = gpd.read_file(inputpath_shapefile_or_geojson_points)

# Plot raster and points

rasterio.plot.show(raster)
print(points)

# Get dataframe with points and coords

coord_list = [(x,y) for x,y in zip(points['geometry'].x , points['geometry'].y)]

points['value'] = [x for x in raster.sample(coord_list)]
points['x'] = points['geometry'].x
points['y'] = points['geometry'].y
points["value"] = points["value"].astype("int64") # or float64
points

# Save csv

points.to_csv(outputpath_csv)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution. It could work if I had a list of point but here I want instead to download each pixel of the initial raster. There size and the amont of raster to work on mak me look for something else than a for loop solution. I've edited to question with my current code to reflect this idea.